# How can I close a window which is using a for loop and thread.sleep

Tags: java

For a school project I have to create a simple canvas on which I have to draw random circles. For this I am using a for loop where I kept spawning circles. To keep my PC from crashing, I used the `Thread.sleep(20)` method. It worked well but had one flaw: it is unable to close itself using the close button.

```
public class CanvasDraw extends Canvas {
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public void paint(Graphics graph){
        setBackground(new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));

        for(int i = 0; i<9999; i++){
            graph.setColor(new Color(rand.nextInt(255), 
                    rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));
            graph.fillOval(rand.nextInt(480), rand.nextInt(480), 120, 120);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        CanvasDraw drawing = new CanvasDraw();

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawing);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't see the Thread.sleep(20); call in this snippet, can you update to show where you put it?

Comment: "*it is unable to close itself using the close button*" .. What do you means but this ?? You mean close button of canvas window ?? If that is the case then Java program itself will terminate .. If this is not the case then what do you mean ??

Answer (score 0):

In your code you paint 10000 ovals each time paint is invoked (which can be quite often). This will clog the event dispatch thread. Paint your ovals on a BufferedImage in your main, and paint that instead. Also extend JComponent instead of Canvas and overwrite paintComponent instead of paint.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

public class CircleDraw {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Random rand = new Random();

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
            g.setColor(new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));
            g.fillOval(rand.nextInt(480), rand.nextInt(480), 120, 120);
        }

        JComponent component = new JComponent() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(component);
        frame.setSize(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to reschedule on the EDT - wrap ui code with EventQueue.invokeLater

Answer (score 0):

Try running your spawning circles loop to run on separate thread.
Don't run it on MAIN thread!!

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple circle animation using Java Swing.  Here's what the GUI looks like.

[image: Circle Animation]

The circle repaints every second with a different color and a different circle radius.  The drawing area is 420 x 420 pixels.  The color varies randomly.  The circle radius varies randomly from 42 pixels to 140 pixels.

The `JFrame` is created in the `run` method of the `CircleAnimation` class.

The drawing panel Is created in the `DrawingPanel` class.  All of the custom painting happens in the `paintComponent` method of the `DrawingPanel` class.

The animation is set up as a `java.swing.Timer` after the `JFrame` is created.  The `Animation` class holds the `ActionListener` for the `Timer`.  The `actionPerformed` method creates a new random color and circle radius.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CircleAnimation implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CircleAnimation());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Animation");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new Animation(drawingPanel));
        timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        timer.start();
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int radius;

        private Color color;

        private Random random;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420, 420));

            this.random = new Random();
            setRandomColorAndRadius();
        }

        public void setRandomColorAndRadius() {
            this.color = new Color(getRandom(0, 255),
                    getRandom(0, 255), getRandom(0, 255));
            int start = getPreferredSize().width / 10;
            int limit = getPreferredSize().width / 3;
            this.radius = getRandom(start, limit);
        }

        private int getRandom(int start, int limit) {
            return random.nextInt(limit - start) + start;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
            int y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
            int width = radius + radius;
            int height = width;
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        }

    }

    public class Animation implements ActionListener {

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        public Animation(DrawingPanel drawingPanel) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            drawingPanel.setRandomColorAndRadius();
            drawingPanel.repaint();
        }

    }

}
```